# Unable to view Support email under project settings Under Project in firebase account

Tags: firebase, oauth, google-oauth, firebase-console

I am trying to fill a OAuth consent screen where i am getting below error. Then i googled and it said we have to add support email in firebase account and use that email here. But I am not seeing support email options under project settings tab under my project .

[image]

I am trying to fill below consent screen and its giving me error as:

> An error occurred while saving your app

[image]

Trying to fill OAuth consent screen and expecting to go to next screen, but there is issue with the support email here

Comment: At first glance the data you entered looks fine. Is there any relevant message showing on the Console tab of your browser's developer tools?